# Simulation generate IID copies

Tags: statistics, simulation

Generate 10 i.i.d copies of a random variable having the p.d.f.

$f(x)=$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2xe^{-x^2/n}1/2^n1/n$

where from what I have found so far

$F(X|N=n)=2^{-n}$

Here's the code I have so far

```
n5=10
u=runif(n5,0,1)
n=ceiling(1/-log(u))
x=2^n*u
```

Comment: First generate a random $N$, then conditional on that $N$ generate $X$ from the distribution with density function proportional to $x\exp(-x^2/N)$.  Then do the whole thing $10$ times over.

Comment: Thanks ! But in order to generate a random N from (1,infinity) I really don't know how.

Comment: Have you checked that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$ like it should?

Comment: Yes, it is equal to one

Comment: Good.  When you checked this, did you evaluate the sum of the integrals, or the integral of the sum?  If  the former case, the sum of the integrals evaluated to $1$, right?

Comment: I evaluated the sum of the integrals. Yes it is equal to 1.

Comment: There's your hint, then.